# Sorting a list of tuples according to another list's string values

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I'm trying to sort a list of financial data according to another list based on financial tickers.

The two lists I have are lists of tuples that contain information about corporations' financial data. `prc_list` is a list of tuples with elements of the form `(company_ticker, price_dataframe)` and `fin_list` is a list of tuples with elements of the form `(company_ticker, financial_dataframe, value)`. Here, "price" simply refers to opening/closing prices and "financial" refers to information you'd typically see when performing fundamental analysis (e.g. ROE, ROA, etc.)

What I'm doing is first I take `fin_list` and sort it in descending order according to a specific quarter and key. For example, if I want to sort all of the companies according to their ROE in 2013-Q3, then the first company would show the relevant information for the company that has the highest ROE value for the third quarter of 2013.

After doing this operation, I want to sort `prc_list` so that the order of tickers matches that of `fin_list`.

My attempts are as follows:

```
prc_list = sorted(prc_list, key=(lambda x: fin_list[x][0]))
# Error -> "List indices must be integers or slices, not tuples."

tic_list = [fin_list[i][0] for i in range(len(fin_list))]
prc_list = sorted(prc_list, key=tic_list)
# Same error.
```

How might one go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
fin_list = [("ticker 1" , "price 1", 10),
            ("ticker 2" , "price 2", 0),
            ("ticker 3" , "price 3", 20),
            ("ticker 4" , "price 4", 14)]

# sort this list
fin_list_sorted = sorted(fin_list, key=lambda x: x[2])
print(fin_list_sorted)

# if you want to sort it in decreasing order
fin_list_sorted = sorted(fin_list, key=lambda x: -x[2])
print(fin_list_sorted)

# if you only want the attributes company_ticker and price_dataframe
prc_list = list(map(lambda x: x[0:2], fin_list_sorted))
print(prc_list)
```